# A weird issue with WebView android

Tags: android, android-layout, svg, webview

I'm trying to display an "svg" image from a string. If I use

`WebView wv =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.wv);
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.loadData(html, mimeType, encoding);`

The image doesn't get displayed but if I use the following lines of code

```
WebView wv=new WebView(this);
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.loadData(html, mimeType, encoding);` 
setContentView(wv);
```

It works. What could be the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another code :

```
private WebView wb;
String html, mimeType, encoding;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
// ... html, encoding, mimeType values
wb = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.widok_web);
openWb();
}

private void openWb() 
{
wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wb.loadData(html, mimeType, encoding);
}
```

Comment: does that make a difference?

Comment: If you see I mentioned that the image is type of "SVG" the html contains xml data for svg.

Answer (score -1):

I add that the mime type needs to be simply "text/html" and not, for example "text/xml" or "image/svg+xml".